# Is it possible to create a controller that extends an abstract controller in grails?

Tags: grails

Im wondering if something like this is possbile:

```
abstract class AbstractController {
  def list = { 
   //default list action 
  }
}

class MyController extends AbstractController {
  def show = { 
   //show action 
  }
}
```

Where `AbstractController` is not visible on the web i.e /app/abstract/list is not accessible and where `MyController` has the actions `list` and `show` and is accessible on the web as /app/my/....

Anyone ever done anything like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting `AbstractController` into `src/groovy` folder.

Though, sharing functionality over Controllers might be not the best idea - it's better to move it to POGO classes or services. This question covers this issue partially: [How do you share common methods in different grails controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195492/how-do-you-share-common-methods-in-different-grails-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

For recent version of grails (3.x as the time of writing) it would be better to use `trait` instead of extending an abstract Controller or use `Mixin`, the later was deprecated since introducing traits in groovy v2.3, here is an example of using a trait to add a generic behaviors to your controller:
1- Create your traits in src/groovy, e.g.

```
import grails.web.Action

trait GenericController {

  @Action
  def test(){
    render "${params}"
  }
}
```

2- Implement your trait as you implement any interface:

```
class PersonController implements GenericController {
    /*def test(){
      render 'override the default action...'
    }*/
}
```

Note: traits can dynamically access all controller objects: params, response... and so on, and you still can override trait's action.

Hope this help.