# Is there a way to make functions accessible across controllers in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to be able to create global functions, meaning a function I can use across controllers, kind of like helper methods.

So in one controller I could do

`useful_function(string)` etc... Is this possible?

I did create a class in src/groovy called `SiteHelper`, am I on the right track? I want the methods of the class `SiteHelper` to be able to be used throughout controllers.

Comment: You can use a groovy category to create this kind of globally accessible function.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195492/how-do-you-share-common-methods-in-different-grails-controllers

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're mostly on the right track. You may want to look at making it as a part of service layer.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html

Comment: I've just completed my first service in Grails, an auth service, this might be more ideal, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can add it to the metaclass of all controller classes, for example in `BootStrap.groovy`:

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      for (cc in grailsApplication.controllerClasses) {
         cc.clazz.metaClass.useful_function = { String s ->
            return ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to share logic between different components in Grails is to put it in a service, or alternatively in a taglib in the case of functions that need access to web-layer things like request/response/params/session/flash. You can call taglib tags as methods from any controller action:

**MyTagLib.groovy**

```
class MyTagLib {
  def sayHello = { attrs, body ->
    out << "Hello ${attrs.name}"
  }
}
```

**MyController.groovy**

```
def someAction() {
  def greeting = sayHello(name:"Ian")
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't get what is nontrivial about this.  It sounds exactly what Apache's `StringUtils` class or `IOUtils` class does.  Yes, creating a `SiteHelper` with static methods and importing it will do what you want and is the typical practice for this in Java-influenced (and many other) languages.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what's incorrect about this?

Comment: I was hoping for a way without importing, possibly autoloading the methods in the controllers, I'm really creating a method called flashmsg() which just flashes a message, which could be useful throughout almost every controller - btw I didn't downvote

Comment: Then you need to make your question clearer to explain this is your need - and I don't really understand what's so anathemic about an `import` statement, the short answer is going to be, "no, you need to import something to use it." Anyway it's not good practice to downvote a correct answer because you're unhappy about the language features available.